# Wrap spring controller return value before handled to MessageConverters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4 - `RestController`. Whatever I am returning from the rest controller method should be wrapped into another object before MessageConverters handles the return value. I want message converters to process that wrapped object instead of actual return value.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("\users")
public class ExampleService{

    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public User getUser(Long id){
       // return user object from DAO
    }

}
```

I want to wrap this `User` object in another class `SccessResponse` which will be ultimate value to be converted to JSON

We have any such extension points?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `User` object with the `SuccessResponse` and return the `SuccessResponse`:

```
@RequestMapping("{id}")
public SuccessResponse getUser(Long id) {
    User user = userDao.findOne(id);
    return new SuccessResponse(user);
}
```

You don't have to use `@ResponseBody` explicitly since you are using `@RestController`. (That's just a side comment; your code is correct in this respect.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have lot of such services and each service have nearly 20 methods. I cannot do that for each service repeatedly.

Comment: You should add that desideratum to the question itself.